# loglog plot in matlab gives log-linear

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot two figures. One linear and one loglog. For some reason the loglog plot is not working correctly. Here is my code:

```
% Define the Lamb-Oseen vortex
y = 1.0;
R = 2.5;

f = @(r) r.*((y/(pi.*(R.^2))) .* exp((-r.^2)/(R.^2)));

% Now calculate the circulation for different n
integrals = zeros(1,4);
error = zeros(1,4);
i = 1;
n = [2,3,4,5];
for k = n
    s = 2*pi*Laguerre_Quad(f, k);
    integrals(1,i) = s;

    error(i) = abs(s - y);
    i = i+1;
end


% Plot results as fcn of n
figure
plot(n,integrals,'r.', 'MarkerSize',30);
title('Calculated Integral vs N');
xlabel('n');
ylabel('Integral');

% Now plot the error as a function of n
figure
loglog(n,error,'r.', 'MarkerSize',30);
title('Error vs N');
xlabel('n');
ylabel('Error');
```

Her are the resulting plots:

Figure 1:

[image: fig1]

Figure 2:

[image: fig2]

Why is the x-axis (n) in figure 2 linear when I have used a loglog plot?

Comment: It's not linear. Notice the distance between 4 and 5 is a lot smaller than the distance between 2 and 3? You just have a very small range.

Comment: Ohhhhh ahaha fair. I was just looking at the values. Cheers